# Sudden "Could not find nokogiri-1.10.7 in any of the sources" error for previously working GAE Ruby Standard Environment deploys

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

It looks like Google has changed the App Engine Ruby Standard runtime in some way that has messed up GAE deploys for a large number of people so I am reporting it here. Deploys that were working two days ago now fail when deployed.

The error is always:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find nokogiri-1.10.7 in any of the sources
```

This occurs regardless of the local state of your code and seems to have nothing to do with bundler configuration, gem versions, or anything like that. If nokogiri is in your app, it won't deploy to gae ruby standard environment right now, period.

This issue has been reported on [Japanese stackoverflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61330/google-app-engine-standard-%e3%81%ae-ruby-beta-%e3%81%a7%e3%83%87%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%a4%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f?newreg=c5eb9b0436474e308986530f7177d2d7) but has not yet received any attention from Google.

Comment: Passed along to the appengine-ruby team (who can quickly get in touch with the gae ruby standard environment team) via a github issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-ruby/issues/31

Comment: I'm responsible for the Ruby runtimes, and I'm looking at this now.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!!!

Comment: This does appear to be related to an App Engine Ruby Runtime release that was being rolled out this week. We are rolling it back while the issue is investigated; the rollback should be complete within the next couple hours.

Comment: update: they have been unable to reproduce so far so I have provided my Gemfile.lock, Gemfile, and cloud build and GAE app logs

Comment: Update: Thanks to the info Sam sent me, we have been able to reproduce this internally. We have a test around this case now, and will make sure it's resolved before pushing out our next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've finished root cause investigation. For the curious, here is what happened:

The Ruby runtime for the App Engine Standard Environment uses [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) to build/install MRI (the standard "Matz" Ruby runtime). On Oct 30, ruby-build [changed its behavior to set --enable-shared](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/pull/1368) when building recent versions of MRI. However, MRI built with the `--enable-shared` setting is not binary-compatible with MRI built without. This can manifest when loading C extensions (such as Nokogiri)... C extensions compiled against MRI built with one setting, will not load successfully in MRI built with the opposite setting.

Prior to the week of Dec 9, the live Ruby runtime was from a build prior to Oct 30, and was thus not built with `--enable-shared`. Then, that week, App Engine started rolling out a new Ruby runtime build that *was* built with `--enable-shared`. The new runtime was incompatible with the old runtime, and thus also with existing applications that included C extensions that were originally compiled against the old runtime, resulting in the symptoms described.

On Dec 11 we rolled the release back as soon as we determined that there was an issue with it. If anyone is still seeing issues, just redeploying your app should resolve them.

To retain compatibility with your existing apps, we will *disable* `--enable-shared` for all future updates of the `ruby25` runtime, and we've put in tests to detect future changes to the runtime compile flags to prevent this from happening again. Note that this does mean that the `ruby25` runtime will always be compiled without dynamic libraries. We are aware that there are a few gems that require dynamic library support, and these will not be supported under the `ruby25` runtime. However, any upcoming `ruby26`, `ruby27`, and later Ruby runtimes, will be built with `--enable-shared`.

Finally, just a note that the official channel for reporting App Engine issues (assuming you do not have a GCP support plan) is to file an issue in the App Engine Issue Tracker. (You can find a link from https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). We're not always checking stack overflow, but the issue trackers feed directly into the internal queues at Google.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your attention to this. I will be sure to use the proper issue tracker in the future (I was not aware these existed). One thing I think this (and my previous issue) highlights though is the awkwardness of having different ruby versions for the build and runtime environments. You would probably prevent a large amount of user frustration (and, indeed, increase GCP sales) if you could coordinate so that build and runtime always use the same ruby version. The current solution (`ruby '~> 2.5.5'`) while reasonable, will break a lot of Gemfiles and in a maddening, unintuitive way.

Comment: Sam: thanks for the feedback. Yes, there is that awkwardness. It's an implication of App Engine's feature where it can swap out the runtime layer under your app (to update the OS, the Ruby installation, security patches, etc.) at any time, and it does so transparently without rerunning the build and bundle install. (So there's actually _never_ a guarantee that build and runtime will always use the same Ruby version.) Part of the goal of the current beta period for the ruby25 runtime is to determine if this is reasonable for real-world Ruby apps.

Comment: I think with a friendly intelligent error message this behavior would be fine. Without it it is frustrating because you end up in a loop of "your Gemfile specified X but your ruby version is Y". Maybe detect if the user has a particular ruby version pegged in Gemfile and suggest a `~>` style peg. The official docs should also mention this imo, and then it would be fine.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. In fact, we had already implemented just such an error message (based on your previous report on stack overflow), and it was one of the very features we were rolling out, when this C extensions issue forced us to roll it back. (The irony is frustrating...) In any case, releases are being frozen for the US holidays, but we'll try to roll it out again after the new year.

Answer (score 0):

updating all the bundle things... Could solve this kind of
**could not find _______ v ___ in any of the sources error**
Just try to run ....

> bundle update --all

Thinking may this solve all bundle problems accordingly..

Comment: `bundle update nokogiri` solved the issue for me,

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva You're a hero.  I have spent hours trying to solve this, and nothing worked until I tried your bundle update suggestion.  And even though the response from bundle was "Bundler attempted to update nokogiri but its version stayed the same", it now works... Go figure!